# Can anyone tell me why this is prompting twice?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I wanted to place two checks to ensure that when the user is prompted, I get some kind of input for it. Then the user would get a check for that input being less than or equal to 1000. Instead its prompting twice..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

int die( const string & msg ){
cout <<"Fatal error: " <<msg <<endl;
exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
} // die 

int main(){
unsigned q, d, n, p, cents; // quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies
cout <<"Quarters (Less than 1000)? " <<endl; 
cin >>q;
if ( q >= 1000 || !( cin>>q ) ) die( "Input failure" );
  cout <<"Dimes (Less than 1000)? " <<endl;
  cin >>d;
if ( d >= 1000 || !( cin>>d ) ) die( "Input failure" );
  cout <<"How many Nickels? (Less than 1000) " <<endl; 
  cin >>n;
if ( n >= 1000 || !( cin>>n ) ) die( "Input failure" );
  cout <<"How many Pennies? (Less than 1000) " <<endl; 
  cin >>p;
if ( p >= 1000 || !( cin>>p ) ) die( "Input failure" );
  cents = (q*25)+(d*10)+(n*5)+p;
  cout <<"That's " <<cents <<" cents!" <<endl;
} // main
```

Did I use the if-else correctly?

Comment: what's that `!(cin>>q)` in the if statements...???

Comment: For starters, its not loop. More importantly you are reading into each variable twice, so your code needs 8! integers to run the whole way.

Comment: You're right, it isn't a loop. Its just an if-else statement without the else. - fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading into each variable twice, only testing if the second read succeeds.

You can remove the unchecked reads and rearrange the condition:

```
cout <<"Quarters (Less than 1000)? " <<endl; 
if ( !(cin >> q) || q >= 1000 ) die( "Input failure" );
```

That would first attempt to read into `q`, and only check its value if the read succeeds.

Comment: Okay.. perhaps I misunderstood how to use cin.. Ill try this, thank you!

Comment: Okay.. looks like it doesn't prompt for input anymore.. after that change

Answer (score 0):

There are at least to methods for what you want:
1) Input failure at any point, cause loop around that input.
2) Input failure at any point, causes restart.

Here's the case for checking each input:

```
int quarter_quantity = 0;
do
{
  quarter_quantity = -1;
  if (cin >> quarter_quantity)
  {
    if ((quarter_quantity >= 0) && (quarter_quantity < 1000))
    {
       break;
    }
  }
  else
  {
     die();
  }
} while (quarter_quantity >= 0);
```

In a similar context, you can have the program loop until all the coin quantities are valid.